# How do I reduce the size of the menu bar?

Tags: themes, gtk, appmenu, metacity

I am trying to make a slim-looking radiance theme. I dont want to switch to linuxmint for slim interfaces, and I like the unity interface more.

I have been able to reduce padding from almost all the file in `theme-name/gtk-3/*.css` and `metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`.

I am still not able to find any place/setting where I can reduce the size of the menu bar. I would like to make it thin. Say 3px or 4px thin.

You can see in the below shown picture I have been able to slim the size of windows border, and also a little bit for the toolbar (although I would like to reduce it more). The menu bar is still thick and big.

Please suggest what shall I do, to make it slim ?
My Theme files.

- [metacity-theme-1.xml](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5723720/)
- [gtk-widgets-backdrop.css](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5723726/)
- [gtk-widgets.css](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5723727/)
- [gtk.css](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5723729/)

[image: Screenshot of my Desktop]

Answer (score 1):

I ran

```
mlocate unity.css
```

and saw there are two other css-files:

> /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css
>
> /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css